# Enforcing contracts for struct fields with auto values, measuring time complexity

Tags: struct, racket, time-complexity

I'm a newbie trying to make basic sense of structures and contracts by making a structure to use as a tool to count procedure calls (in my class we're just getting into time complexity) Basically, I'm wondering if you can enforce contracts on structure fields with auto-values.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
#lang racket
(struct counter (name [count #:mutable #:auto])
  #:auto-value 0
  #:property prop:procedure
  (lambda(c-id)
    (set-counter-count! c-id (add1 (counter-count c-id)))))

(define (counter-print! counter)
  (printf "~a: ~a\n" (counter-name counter) (counter-count counter)))

(define (counter-reset! counter)
  (set-counter-count! counter 0))

(provide (contract-out (struct counter ([name string?]
                                        [count integer?])))
         counter-print! counter-reset!)
```

I'd use the structure by defining counters out in front of a procedure of interest, inserting calls to the counter where I want to count internal procedure calls, and then repeatedly running the procedure with varying input sizes and printing/reseting the counters (You can let me know if this is a boneheaded way to gather data about complexity too).

Now I know my code doesn't work because the contract seems to enforce that counter takes 2 parameters, but the structure definition has it that counter takes 1. A simple fix would be to remove the auto keywords, but I'm wondering if there is a way to have count automatically set to 0 yet still enforce, in order to make the data-type more secure, that set-counter-count! fails when called on a non-integer value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never seem to use `#:auto` because it never seems to work quite the way I hope.

In this case I think I'd simply `provide` contracts for the individual `struct` constructor and accessor functions:

```
(provide (contract-out [counter (-> string? counter?)]
                       [counter-count (-> counter? integer?)]
                       [counter-name (-> counter? string?)])
         counter-print! counter-reset!)
```

And use like so:

```
#lang racket

(require "counter.rkt")

(define c (counter "a"))
(counter-name c)  ;=> "a"
(counter-count c) ;=> 0
(c) ;increment
(counter-count c) ;=> 1
```

---

Having said all that, for what you're describing I think I'd probably just use a mutable hash-table. Also, I'd probably make the hash-table keys be `procedure?` not `string?`. For instance:

```
(define ht (make-hash)) ;(hash/c procedure? integer?)

(define (increment-counter proc)
  (hash-update! ht
                proc
                (λ (v) (add1 v))
                0))

(define (get-counter proc)
  (hash-ref ht proc #f))

(increment-counter display)
(get-counter display) ;=> 1
(increment-counter display)
(get-counter display) ;=> 2

(increment-counter displayln)
(get-counter displayln) ;=> 1

ht ;=> '#hash((#<procedure:displayln> . 1) (#<procedure:display> . 2))
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked into hash-tables before but they do seem like a simpler solution. Also, could you explain the advantage to using procedures as keys?